# New window inside a main window?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am a beginner and I am trying to make a text editor and I want to create a pop up window for text format when I press a menu button where I can put all things like font face, font size , font style etc. Can you tell me how I can make this new window?  Thanks for your patience!

For example Notepad:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're after is a dialog of some kind.

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

What I would do is design the basic UI onto a `JPanel`.  I would then add this `JPanel` to an instance of a `JDialog` (possibly even using a `JOptionPane`) and show this dialog, making sure to make it modal, so you can easily retrieve the values set by the user.

This means that you can decide how best to show the user interface or even show it in a number of different ways as it's not constrained to a single top level container

Comment: I added an example of what I want to make :)

Comment: @SiminaAlin Certainly doable.  A dialog of some kind would be a good choice to display it within...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a brand spanking new JFrame and it will still be counted as the same application.

Tip: Use Eclipse Window Builder